# Regex from another domain?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to make an automated process to retrieve some information from a site on my work network.

```
var duderegex = new RegExp("Title for Mr. [^\n]+","m");
var dude = duderegex.exec(input);
```

So far, so good.  The problem is that I'm writing this on my work computer and probably won't be able to convince anyone to store this on the same domain as the site that is hosting it.  So that technically makes it XSS.  And I'd rather not have to get approval to install anything seriously funky (so I can't guarantee JQuery or a powershell that's easier to copy/paste from, for example).

I don't have any problems downloading files and manipulating them via webpage after download, but that adds a step clicking Save As...

Does anyone have any workable solutions for running regex on HTML source from a different domain?  I don't need to limit it to Javascript, but getting PHP to work, for example, might require more resources than I have.

A commenter asked for clarification, so here goes.  Let's say I have to contact 50 copyright holders a day (it has nothing to do with intellectual property but it will work).  Right now, I have a form that takes me to

```
(1) http://foo.bar/form.htm?action=search&type=ArtistAlbum&Artist=Beatles&Album=White
```

and redirects to

```
(2) http://foo.bar/form.htm?id=4578469
```

From there, I click on a dropdown (let's say track listing), and that takes me to

```
(3) http://foo.bar/form.htm?id=4578469&track=7
```

There I have an alphabetical list of everyone who worked on the track, their agents, and legal representatives.  I'm only interested in three names, the name of the person who holds the copyright of the lyrics, the name of the person who holds the copyright for the melody, and the name of the person who holds the copyright of the recording.  So I have to search the document three times.

Since each name has a standard title, I should be able to write a script that asks for the artist and album, generates the link to (1), either copies the param from the url for (2) or uses a regex to find it from the link to (3), loads page (3), and then generates the output for a regex on the strings

```
/Lyrics Copyright Holder [^\n]+/
/Melody Copyright Holder [^\n]+/
/Performance Copyright Holder [^\n]+/
```

I could download all the files (it would take a *long* time), but the information changes on occasion, and I want to make sure I'm always pulling the newest information.

But I can't seem to get around the XSS bit.

Comment: There's nothing to install with jQuery

Comment: Oh, and don't write regular expressions like that. Use the literal form: `/Title for Mr\. [^\n]+/m`

Comment: Those regexes won't work, you need to replace `[^/n]` with `[^\n]`. The difference between `/` and ``\`` is rather significant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what problem you're really trying to solve so it's a little hard to know what solutions make the most sense for you, but you can write javascript that works on any web page in a browser plug-in (like in Chrome or Firefox) or by using a scripting language outside of a browser (Python, Javascript, PHP, etc...) where you load the page contents and then manipulate the contents using the language tools.

Comment: Essentially, the issue is that part of my job is looking up some guy in a directory to send correspondence to.

I'll add a sample scenario up top.